# Remove white spaces from a KQL string: Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, removing-whitespace, kusto-explorer, trailing-whitespace

I have a string

```
let String = "     Test  ";
```

I need an output as below:

Output = Test

I have tried using `trim()`, `trimstart()`, `trimend()`
Only one space has been removed using these scalar functions.

Answer (score 1):

Please try [`trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/trimfunction) with Regex `\s` for whitespaces:

```
let String = " Test ";
print a = String, b = trim(@"\s", String)
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is fine, however **(1)** You are using a very convenient use-case, for which the OP naive solution (`trim(" ", String)') would also have worked. **(2)** Please avoid the use of images unless absolutely necessary. In this case you can use [unicode_codepoints_to_string()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/unicode-codepoints-to-string-function) to show the content of the original text vs. the altered text.

Answer (score 0):

Found the work-around using **replace_regex(source,lookup_regex, rewrite_pattern)**

Pass the string value as source, lookup_regex as " " *(nothing but blank spaces)*, rewrite_pattern as "" *(replace with no space)*

**Example**:

Input: let String = "     Test  "; //String length is 11

print(replace_regex(String," ", ""))    *Output is: Test (String length is 4)*

--Happy Coding:)

Comment: Nope. That code removes *all* spaces in the text, including mid text.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To replace more than one  trailing and leading space character  , We can use regular expression  `[trim(@"[ \t]+",<string_to_replace>)]` in [trim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/trimfunction)

```sql
let String = "   Te.  se   st.    ";

print original_string = String replacing_all_space_via_regex= trim(@"[ \t]+",String)

//Other possible methods to replace just the single occurrence of space

//print original_string = String, replacing_single_space_via_space_character = trim(@" ", String)

//print original_string = String replacing_single_space_via_regex = trim(@"[ \t]",String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all spaces from a string:

```
let String = "   s idan   mor  ";
print replace_string(String, " ", ""); // output will be "sidanmor"
```

[image]